# Apache is not executing PHP scripts

Tags: php, apache

I changed the httpd.conf as follows:

- Replaced

  ```
  DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs"
  ```

  with

  ```
  DocumentRoot "C:/Temp/WebServerCore/Binaries/html"
  ```
- Replaced

  ```
  <Directory "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs">
  ```

  with

  ```
  <Directory "C:/Temp/WebServerCore/Binaries/html">
  ```

However Apache does not recognize the php code in my .html file. What other changes do I need to make for Apache to execute PHP?

Comment: You need to use `.php` files, not `.html` files.  Or you'll need to edit the config to tell it to execute `.html` files as PHP.

Comment: There was the exact question a few hours ago.

Comment: This belongs on http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 4):

It is by design. Apache will not parse PHP code inside a HTML file by default. You can include HTML codes in a PHP file as you would code them in a HTML document.

Renames your files and add extension `.php` at the end they will parsed as you want.

Or you can configure your apache configuration (httpd.conf) to parse PHP code inside HTML too.

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm
```

Or you can match extension and set their handlers like

```
<FilesMatch "\.(htm|html|php)$">
     SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: apache doesn't render. it's just that by default .html files are not passed through the php module. **ANY** file can be configured in apache to be treated as a PHP script.

Comment: @MarcB, :) True, I have modified my answer.

Comment: It does not work either. When my .html files are in the default directory "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs" it works fine, when I change it to "C:/Temp/WebServerCore/Binaries/html" and mmove my .html files to the new location PHP is not executed by Apache.

Comment: @user2495173, Does the location exists? And are you opening your files through localhost or your server and not by simple double clicking it?

Comment: @Starx: I am opening it on the browser by login into the application and a different .html page calls this .html page which has the php code in it.

Comment: @user2495173, Are you opening like this `http://localhost/link/to/your/file.hmlt?`

Comment: @Starx: No I am not opening the link from my localhost, i use a secured https://birs.DNS:7500/Login which will display my .html with php code

Comment: @user2495173 Does your configuration set to show html page like I have shown in my anser.

Comment: @Starx: Yes httpd.conf has <<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
 </FilesMatch>
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm

Comment: @user2495173 That is wrong. Wait for my update